# Reading in no-default-ctor data from a stream - what's the common idiom?

Tags: c++, input, constructor, default-constructor, istream

I have a `class Foo` with no default ctor. You know what? Suppose it's completely immutable after construction. Suppose also that I can't add code it (i.e. no additional ctors, friends etc. allowed.)

Now, I want to be able to read data for a foo instance from a stream and construct a foo accordingly, e.g. if `Foo` has fields `x` and `y` I want to support the user inputting `"foo[x =1,y=2]"` (never mind the exact syntax).

Now, when you want to read something from a stream you would usually like to be to do:

```
Foo my_foo;
std::cin >> foo;
```

But this won't work, since no default ctor. (Frankly, I don't like `operator>>` even for types for which this can work.)

Now, instead, I could:

1. Use a templatized `X read(istream& is)` function, whose default definition uses the code above, but which I could specialize for types with no default ctor.
2. Just not use `operator>>` except for very basic types; always use the available ctors, and forget about a generic way of reading from input.
3. Something else.

So, my questions are:

- Is there a "something else"? Another idiom for this task?
- Is option 1 considered good practice?

Comment: Your first approach is similar to what Boost.Serialization does. It works fine.

Comment: @Quentin: Maybe I should just use some facility from Boost.Serialization then? Or is it overkill?

Comment: From my experience with Boost.Serialization (read: using it for a hobby project to see how it behaves), it's a very, very good library but with quite a steep learning curve, and the documentation isn't ideal. On the other hand, it does literally everything you'd need to (de)serialize an object graph automagically (pointer tracking, error detection and all).

Comment: @Quentin: The question is whether it's easily usable for simple things like de-serializing my `foo[x=1, y=2]` and maybe configurably accepting also `foo[y=2, x=1]` etc.

Comment: If all you need is parsing and instancing, not really, no. Still, it's a hint towards the viability of the "default impl + specialized versions" pattern. As a technical note, you'll probably want a layer of indirection in here, as function template specializations are a bit clunky.